# pass the variable from module to js file

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I have created my custom module.I need to passed the fetched database value $flag=1 to js file in drupal 7.In js file I caught 'undefined variable aniv' in js file

```
module file
$flag=1; //assume fetched from database 
drupal_add_js(array('one_time_popup' => array('aniv' => $flag)), array('type' => 'setting'));
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'one_time_popup') . '/service.js','file');
$settings=variable_get('one_time_popup_effects',(ONE_TIME_POPUP_DEFAULT)); 
drupal_add_js(array('onetimepopupmenu'=>$settings),'settings');

service.js
console.log(Drupal.settings.one_time_popup.aniv);
```

Comment: have you checked the page after clearing the javascript cache / drupal cache.

Comment: ya checked but no luck

Comment: I can use console log to view the variables console.log(Drupal.settings.onetimepopupmenu); and console.log(Drupal.settings.one_time_popup.aniv); after writing $flag=1; //assume fetched from database 
  drupal_add_js(array('one_time_popup' => array('aniv' => $flag)), array('type' => 'setting'));
  drupal_add_js(array('onetimepopupmenu'=>'yes'), array('type' => 'setting')); in the init function of the module

Comment: are you sure your above code is getting executed in your inc / module file.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/how-to-send-variable-from-php-file-to-js-file

Comment: What is the hook name in which your php code executes?

Comment: user_login hook.now its working

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible problem is the line

```
drupal_add_js(array('onetimepopupmenu'=>$settings),'settings');
```

It should be `setting` not `settings`

```
drupal_add_js(array('onetimepopupmenu'=>$settings),'setting');
```